# Recuperando objetos do DOM ordenados por um critério

Tags: jquery

Teria como capturar todos os objetos do DOM e ordená-los por um conjunto de regras. 
Por exemplo, no código abaixo os atributos data-gs-x="0" data-gs-y="0" definem a posição (x, y) em tela. Gostaria de pegar os elementos considerando a ordem das coordenadas.

O retorno deveria seguir a ordem:

1. Objeto (0,0)
2. Objeto (4,0)
3. Objeto (8,0)
4. Objeto (0,4)
5. Objeto (4,4)
6. Objeto (8,4)
7. Objeto (0,8)
8. Objeto (4,8)

```html
<div data-gs-x="0" data-gs-y="0" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="4" class="grid-stack-item ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-resizable-autohide"> </div>
<div data-gs-x="4" data-gs-y="0" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="4" class="grid-stack-item ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-resizable-autohide"> </div>
<div data-gs-x="8" data-gs-y="0" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="4" class="grid-stack-item ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-resizable-autohide"> </div>
<div data-gs-x="0" data-gs-y="4" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="4" class="grid-stack-item ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-resizable-autohide"> </div>
<div data-gs-x="4" data-gs-y="4" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="4" class="grid-stack-item ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-resizable-autohide"> </div>
<div data-gs-x="8" data-gs-y="4" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="4" class="grid-stack-item ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-resizable-autohide"> </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Resolvi um pouco diferente dos colegas. Achei que ficou mais simples.
Criei esse [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bnascimento/0qdbwut1/) também.

```js
var $obj = $('.testGrid');

$obj.find('.test').sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.dataset.gsX - b.dataset.gsX;
  })
  .sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.dataset.gsY - b.dataset.gsY;
  })
  .appendTo($obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testGrid">
  <div class="test" data-gs-x="8" data-gs-y="4" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="4" class="grid-stack-item ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-resizable-autohide"> 6</div>
  <div class="test" data-gs-x="0" data-gs-y="0" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="4" class="grid-stack-item ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-resizable-autohide"> 1</div>
  <div class="test" data-gs-x="4" data-gs-y="4" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="4" class="grid-stack-item ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-resizable-autohide"> 5</div>
  <div class="test" data-gs-x="8" data-gs-y="0" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="4" class="grid-stack-item ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-resizable-autohide">3 </div>
  <div class="test" data-gs-x="0" data-gs-y="4" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="4" class="grid-stack-item ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-resizable-autohide"> 4</div>
  <div class="test" data-gs-x="4" data-gs-y="0" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="4" class="grid-stack-item ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-resizable-autohide"> 2</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cara,

eu não entendi o que você quis dizer por ordem das coordenadas, mas eu fiz um exemplo de como você pode customizar a ordenação de um array.

**HTML**

```
<div data-gs-x="8" data-gs-y="0" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="4" class="grid-stack-item ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-resizable-autohide"> 
80
</div>
<div data-gs-x="0" data-gs-y="4" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="4" class="grid-stack-item ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-resizable-autohide"> 
04
</div>
<div data-gs-x="4" data-gs-y="4" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="4" class="grid-stack-item ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-resizable-autohide"> 
44
</div>
<div data-gs-x="8" data-gs-y="4" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="4" class="grid-stack-item ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-resizable-autohide"> 
84
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function compare(a, b){
    if($(a).attr('data-gs-x') < $(b).attr('data-gs-x')){
        return -1;
    }else if($(a).attr('data-gs-x') == $(b).attr('data-gs-x')){
        if($(a).attr('data-gs-y') < $(b).attr('data-gs-y')){
            return -1;
        }else if($(a).attr('data-gs-y') == $(b).attr('data-gs-y')){
            return 0
        }else{
            return 1;
        }
    }else{
        return 1;
    }
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    data = $('.grid-stack-item');
    data.sort(compare);
    $(this.body).append('<div>Resultado</div>')
    data.each(function(){
        $(document.body).append('<div>'+$(this).attr('data-gs-x')+''+$(this).attr('data-gs-y')+'</div>');
    })
});
```

Basicamente você deve criar uma função recebendo dois parametros e comparar eles da maneira que for necessária. Assim quando chamar a função `data_array.sort(funcao_compara)` as regras que você definiu serão utilizadas.

Fiz esse exemplo ordenando primeiro pelos valores de x e depois pelos valores de y.

Criei esse [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lovzdj5L/6/) também